# Are boolean expressions in XPath case-sensitive?

Tags: xpath

From the examples of [`AndExpr`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-AndExpr) and [`OrExpr`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-OrExpr) in the [Booleans section of the XPath spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans), it's clear that lowercase words (`and`, `or`) are valid.  However, this doc does not explicitly mention whether upper-case (`AND`, `OR`), or mixed-case variants of these keywords are valid.

Are non-lowercase variants of these keywords valid?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, boolean expression operators are case-sensitive.

No, `AND` and `OR` are not legal boolean operator keywords in XPath.

The BNF you cite clearly shows lower case `and` and `or` and mentions nothing about case insensitivity.  Keywords in most languages are case-sensitive.

Any compliant XPath processor will emit an error upon encountering `AND` or `OR` where `and` or `or` are expected.

Comment: I might add that in the XML world nearly everything is case-sensitive. The only exceptions are things like language codes and encoding names that are defined by standards outwith the XML stack.